# My Save Button throws an Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom

I am going to create Wizard for custom object `Vehicle__c`. My fields are `Vehicle_Number__c,Vehicle_Owner__c,Vehicle_Type__c(Pick list )` while saving in third page am getting an Error.

This is my Apex Code:

```
public class Vehicletest {
public Vehicle__c Fed{get;set;}

 public Vehicle__c getFed() {
      if(Fed== null) Fed = new Vehicle__c();
      return Fed;
   }
    public PageReference step1() {
      return Page.Newtest;
   }

   public PageReference step2() {
      return Page.Newtest2;
   }

   public PageReference step3() {
      return Page.Newtest3;
   }
 public PageReference cancel() {
            PageReference FeedbackPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed).view();
            FeedbackPage.setRedirect(true);
            return FeedbackPage; 
    }
public PageReference save() {

PageReference FeedbackPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(Fed).view();
      FeedbackPage.setRedirect(true);

      return FeedbackPage;
   }

}
```

this is my Vf Code:

```
<apex:page controller="Vehicletest" tabStyle="Vehicle__c">
  <script>
  function confirmCancel() {
      var isCancel = confirm("Are you sure you wish to cancel?");
      if (isCancel) return true;

     return false;
  }  
  </script>
  <apex:sectionHeader title="New Customer Opportunity" subtitle="Step 1 of 3"/>
    <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Customer Information" mode="edit">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
          <apex:commandButton action="{!step2}" value="Previous"/>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" 
                              onclick="return confirmCancel()" immediate="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Information">

        <!-- Within a pageBlockSection, inputFields always display with their
             corresponding output label. -->
       <apex:inputField id="myPicklist" required="true" value="{!Fed.Vehicle_Type__c}"/><br /> <br /> 
              </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But am getting "Argument cannot be null" Error for save Button

Answer (score 1):

@Novarg is right, that you've not define `Fed` correctly. That's why you're getting an error. Remove `getFed()` method since it can be done using `get` property in `public Vehicle__c Fed{get;set;}` itself. You should define `Fed` something like this:

```
public Vehicle__c Fed {
    get { 
        if(Fed== null) 
            Fed = new Vehicle__c();
        return Fed; 
    }
    set;
}
```

Refer documentation for [`get;set;`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Fed` is `null` when you click *Save* button.

You do not initialize it anywhere, except for `getFed()` method, which you do not call anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
public Vehicle__c getFed() {
  if(Fed== null) Fed = new Vehicle__c();
  return Fed;
}
```

And add below code ( initialize the variable in the constructor )

```
public Vehicletest(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
          Fed = new Vehicle__c();
}
```